# Buscador con la librería ISOTOPE | Consulta de Filtrado de categorías

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Que tal? estoy realizando un pequeño portafolio de imágenes con la librería ISOTOPE de github.

El caso es que estoy realizando un buscador, donde al momento que el usuario escriba algo en input este devuelva la categoría de esa imagen.

Un ejemplo muy claro es el de esta web: http://dynamic-search.webflow.io/

En el tiene un buscador donde al escribir su categoria o etiqueta, este o estos se llaman automáticamente.

HTML de ejemplo: En este caso, estoy usando la etiqueta (data-tipo) para a los atributos que tendra la categoria.

```
<div class="item" 
 data-categoria="Sketches" 
 data-tipo="Sketches ebook Boceto" 
 data-description=" Ebook Sketch | PSD">
    <div class="item-content all Sketches ">
     <img src="imgport/skecth-ebook.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CODE JS: Ya di con el codigo, ya puedo acceder a las datas por medio de forEarch y getAttribute y también podemos obtener lo que esta copiando el usuario, pero como conecto estas 2 funciones y que me traigan las images de data-tipo?

```
$(function () {



document.querySelectorAll('.grid .item').forEach((element) => {

const datas = element.getAttribute('data-tipo');

document.querySelector('#busqueda').addEventListener('input', (evento) => {

const busqueda  = evento.target.value;



});

});

});
```

**Ejemplo:** Si yo escribo Ebook, que me traiga las images que contenga la palabra ebook, si escribo boceto que me traiga todo los imagenes con que contenga ese atributo en data-tipo.

Si alguien ha trabajado con esta librería o tenga nociones y pueda instruirme un poco. Se le agradeceria mucho!.

**Update:** 
Encontre una pequeña codigo que resulta pero solo para el nombre de las etiquetas, a eso le añadi para que devolviera todo el contenido de las etiquetas. Pero creo que estoy referenciando mal.

Donde dice "Aca" es donde tengo la inicialización, lo que hace es devolver el texto del tipeado del search field y luego las imágenes, aunque estoy tratando de que me reconozca los data-tipo que hay en los divs.

```
var qsRegex; /*Variable global para pasar a la funcion de mas abajo*/

function atributos()
{
/*Devuelvo las etiquetas*/
document.querySelectorAll('.grid .item').forEach((element) => {

const datas = element.getAttribute('data-tipo');

qsRegex = datas;

});
}

console.log(qsRegex);
/*Aca*/
$(function () {

    var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  filter: function() {
    return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
  }
});



var $busqueda = $('.busqueda').keyup( debounce( function() {
  qsRegex = new RegExp( $busqueda.val(), 'gi' );
  $grid.isotope();
}, 200 ) );



});

function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
  var timeout;
  threshold = threshold || 100;
  return function debounced() {
    clearTimeout( timeout );
    var args = arguments;
    var _this = this;
    function delayed() {
      fn.apply( _this, args );
    }
    timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold );
  };
}
```

documentacion:https://isotope.metafizzy.co/